# Fetch api is not working in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch api in react native using following code snippet

```
fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'stephen'
  })
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

But it gives an error saying `then of undefined`. Any kind of help would be appreciated. (I'm using a local url as the REQUEST_URL)

Comment: the code looks alright. Can you check
 - that the error is from this specific part of the code
 - your url is correct, and works via apps like curl/ postman

Comment: yes nabn, my url is working on a postman with the body parameters

Comment: Please provide the full error stack trace... your error isn't enough to go on, especially if you're saying the URL is good.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about that, but I guess you needs fetch polyfill:

```
npm install whatwg-fetch --save
```

and

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

If you want to know more visit https://github.com/github/fetch